# How to use %d to insert an array into a string of text?

Tags: python, arrays, vector

As a beginner at Python, I have learnt that when you want to insert some variable into a string of text, you use the generic format of

```
"Blah blah blah %d" % some_variable
```

And it will output

```
"Blah blah blah some_variable"
```

I am usually okay at doing this, but I think my problem is because I'm trying to use %d to insert a vector/array of numbers instead of one single item.

Please see below my full code that I'm trying to run, and it doesn't work!

```
import statistics

list = [10, 2, 6, 12, 14, 15, 15, 24, 15, 25, 3, 12]

def average(array):
    print "The mean is of %d is %d" % array, statistics.mean(list)

average(list)
```

I'm wondering if maybe I need to use a different % operator? Or maybe it's not possible because of the fact that it is indeed a vector?

Comment: The newer style of formatting is probably easier: `print "The mean is of {} is {}".format(lst, statistics.mean(lst))`. There's variations too introduced in python 3 that won't work in P2 (I think you have a mix in your code snippet?). See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples). Also, avoid using `list` as a name for lists as it is a python builtin.

Comment: Use numbered string formatting: `"{0}, {1}".format("Hello", "World") == "Hello, World"`, `"{1}, {0}".format("Hello", "World") == "World, Hello"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%s` can be used to represent any data. `str` will be called to convert the object to a string.

You should also enclose multiple items in a tuple. Putting it all together:

```
print "The mean is of %s is %d" % (array, statistics.mean(array))
```

Comment: No, `"%s" % X` uses `str(X)`, while `"%r" % X` uses `repr(X)`.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Mea culpa; updating accordingly.

Comment: Please add a line how to write a tuple, too, because in OPs example the comma is wrong.